# How to go from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy?

Tags: r, date, format

The follwing code:

```
date.seq <- as.Date("2007-10-01"):as.Date("2007-10-31")
new.dates <- data.frame(date = as.Date(date.seq, origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

gives the following output:

```
> new.dates
  date
1 2007-10-01
2 2007-10-02
3 2007-10-03
4 2007-10-04
5 2007-10-05
```

I would like to have the dates in dd-mm-yyyy format.

I have tried `as.Date(new.dates, "%d/%m/%y")` without succes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a) Parse

```
d <- as.Date( "06.12.2012", "%d.%m.%Y")
```

b) Format

```
strftime(d, "%m-%d-%Y")
```

or

```
format(d, "%m-%d-%Y")
```

so Find the below code.

```
date.seq <- as.Date("2007-10-01"):as.Date("2007-10-31")
new.dates <- data.frame(date = as.Date(date.seq, origin = "1970-01-01"))
new.dates1 <- as.Date( new.dates$date, "%d.%m.%Y")
strftime(new.dates1, "%m-%d-%Y")
```

Comment: There was similar thread in the forum - next time search through the forum. If you find this anwser useful upvote

Comment: Could you please be more specific and relate your answer to the code I provided? I need to create the range of dates first as seen in the code I provided.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach. Just for fun:

```
sub("^(.*)-(.*-)(.*)$", "\\3-\\2\\1", new.dates[[1]])

#  [1] "01-10-2007" "02-10-2007" "03-10-2007" "04-10-2007" "05-10-2007"
#  [6] "06-10-2007" "07-10-2007" "08-10-2007" "09-10-2007" "10-10-2007"
# [11] "11-10-2007" "12-10-2007" "13-10-2007" "14-10-2007" "15-10-2007"
# [16] "16-10-2007" "17-10-2007" "18-10-2007" "19-10-2007" "20-10-2007"
# [21] "21-10-2007" "22-10-2007" "23-10-2007" "24-10-2007" "25-10-2007"
# [26] "26-10-2007" "27-10-2007" "28-10-2007" "29-10-2007" "30-10-2007"
# [31] "31-10-2007"
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
new.dates <- data.frame(format(as.Date(1:31, origin = "1970-01-01"),"%d/%m/%Y"))
```

In your original code, `as.Date(start):as.Date(end)` creates a vector of integers, which you transform back to date using `as.Date(...)` a second time.